# 4 digits username - CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, user-registration

I got a small page with a registration form. When users would like to register, they just have to click on a button and a four digit random number will be generated.

To do so, I got the following idea. I'll render a form for the username and define "Temp" as default value. If the user clicks on "Register" a "Temp"-User will be added. Now I'll update the users table and change the username to a random code with the following mysql statement:

```
 'UPDATE `users` SET `username` = FLOOR( 1000 + ( RAND( ) 
*8999 ) ) WHERE id = ' + $this->Auth->user('id') + ';'
```

This is the whole php code.

```
   $this->User->query('UPDATE `users` SET `username` = FLOOR( 1000 + ( RAND( )
 *8999 ) ) WHERE id = ' + $this->Auth->user('id') + ';');
```

But this doesn't work. What do you think? What is the best solution to create an automatically generated username?

Update: Thanks 'kinjal'

```
    $this->User->query('UPDATE `users` SET `username` = FLOOR( 1000 + ( RAND( ) 
*8999 ) ) WHERE id = '.$this->Auth->user('id').';');
```

Comment: multi-lingual issue.  in php for concatenation try . instead of +

Comment: Thank u for the hint =) But it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You do not desire more than 8999 users...?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are using plus signs where you should be using full stops to concatenate variables and strings.

You should generate the username in Cake, that way you can use the `isUnique` validation in the model, if you want to do it in MySQL you would need a large sub query of all previous user names.

You should also generate the username before inserting it into the database, this would stop you having to go back and edit that row, which seems a very odd way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a temp user and then changing the username you could in your table enable AUTO_INCREMENT on the username field, create the first user manually and set it's username to 1000.

You then won't have to figure out the username but any user you create after that will have username 1001, 1002, 1003 .... etc.

This approach is sort of unorthodox though.